# [wireshark]how to use a plug-in to dissect a packet

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

our team is currently working on building a wireshark dissector which dissect a certain type of packet. we have build our packet based on a template.

Say the name of the plug in we build is ABC, now our goal is that whenever we type ABC in the filter box in wireshark, we want to see(capture) the packet we sent. [image]

As you may see in the image, if we filter it by ip.destination, wireshark knows these are the packet we are interested in. the current task is that when I type the plug-in name ABC, I want the same result.

I do apologize if the question is not crystal clear, we just get started and still in a initial phase. Any tip or suggestion is GREATLY GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make your plugin dissector as you would normally do, as documented in [this](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html) page. As stated in the link, when you register your protocol using `proto_register_protocol()` under `proto_register_ABC()`, the abbrev string provided as the third argument is registered as the filter name.

Information regarding creating plugins can be found in the "doc/README.plugins" file.

If you want to register filters for data structures within your packet(you can see the above link for instructions again), look for the function proto_register_ABC() (here ABC is your protocol name), add your data member to the static array "hf_register_info hf[]" as shown below.

```
void 
proto_register_ABC(void)
{
    static hf_register_info hf[] = {
        { &hf_foo,
          { "FOO member", "foo", FT_BYTES,
            BASE_NONE, NULL, 0x0, NULL, HFILL }}
        };
```

hf_foo will have to be declared. 
You second string in :

```
{ "FOO member", "ABC", FT_BYTES,
                BASE_NONE, NULL, 0x0, NULL, HFILL }}
```

i.e. the second string "foo" is your filter name.

Now if your dissector function `dissect_ABC()` works correctly, then you'll be able to filter your protocol packets using "ABC" automatically. You can also look at how this is done for other dissection like "TCP" for examples. Look under "epan/dissectors/packet-tcp.c".